# (PHP) Data or connection somehow lost after page reloading

Tags: php, session, reload

As in the title, my script losts data or connection (I'm not sure), after the page is reloaded. Session stays set.
My site looks like this scheme https://i.stack.imgur.com/lssv2.jpg

It is partially in Polish, so I give translation:
Hasło = password
logowanie = logging

and here is index.php code, where it all happens...

```
session_start();

if ((isset($_SESSION['logged']))) { 
    require "panel.php"; 
} else {
    if ((!isset($_POST['login'])) || (!isset($_POST['haslo']))) { 
        require "logowanie.php"; 
    } else {
        require "config.php";
        $db = mysqli_connect($dbh, $dblog, $dbpass, $dbn);

        $login=$_POST['login'];
        $haslo=md5($_POST['haslo']);

        $login=htmlentities($login, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $haslo=htmlentities($haslo, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $query="SELECT * FROM `rej_obywatele` WHERE `login`='".$login."' AND     `haslo`='".$haslo."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
        $userid = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 

        if ($result) {
            $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($numrows==1) {
                $_SESSION['logged']=true;
                $_SESSION['id']=$userid['id'];
                echo session_id();

                require "panel.php";
            } else {
                require "logowanie.php";
                echo "<h3>FALSE LOGIN OR PASSWORD</h3>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is panel.php

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){ 
    header('Location:index.php'); 
} else {
    require "config.php";

    $query="SELECT * FROM `rej_obywatele` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 

    echo $user['imie']." ".$user['nazwisko']; //I cant see it after reload
```

I suppose it is something with isset's in index.php but I cant figure out how to fix it since many hours :/

Comment: im not sure what you are asking, what exactly is "lost" be reloading the page?i see your taking post values from somewhere? they wont be present on a page load unless its been posted to

Comment: do NOT use `htmlentities` to escape SQL. use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, or better yet use parameterized queries. Also do not use `md5` by itself for password hashing, read up on salting passwords. Your database will be vulnerable to rainbow table attack if you do not.

Comment: $_POST are taken from logowanie.php - this is segment ment for logging in ;) And lost are values from panel.php. For example    echo $user['imie']." ".$user['nazwisko']; is an empty line after loading segment of the right side of the site. Before loading this data is shown correctly.

Comment: I figured out how to fix it. Update is in my question.